# asp.net web api using existing database for token authentication and user authorization

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity-2

I need to build a RESTfull web service using OAuth, bearer access_token and refresh_token. Authentication and authorization should be done by checking existing sql db.
The web api template, provided by VS2013 writes/reads in/from its own local sqlexpress db by this connectionString:

```
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApiTest-20150423094253.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApiTest-20150423094253;Integrated Security=True"
```

After hours of googling, I just got tutorials and examples, which do not match with my issue.
So how can I bind my db into the project for authentication/athorization?

Comment: you can always use your own connection string.

Comment: yes, but i need to have custom tables not the default tables that provide by identity framework.

Comment: Then create a custom provider to handle the authentication

Comment: i'm kind of new to asp web authentication ,so if you have some references can you guys provide them